# Angular Dragula and ng-repeat $index

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dragula, angular-dragula

I have an ng-repeat of rows.  I set them up so you can reorder them with drag-and-drop using Angular Dragula. This works fine, but the ng-repeat `$index` remains the initial value for each item after dragging.  See screen captures below before and after a drag of the "Recipient" row.

Is there a way to update the index? I also want to re-order the menu with javascript, with that button in each row, but for that to work I need to get the current $index (and decrement/increment it) and that won't work if the index is incorrect like this.

### Before Drag

[image]

### After Drag

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this is the answer:

```
 <div class="table-cards-body" dragula="'first-bag'" dragula-model="home.quickReceiveFields">

      <div class="table-cards-row drag-item" ng-repeat="field in home.quickReceiveFields track by $index">
        <div class="one">{{field.name}}</div>
        <div class="two">{{field.type}}</div>
        <div class="three">{{field.default}} {{$index}}</div>
        <div class="four"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.display"></div>
        <div class="five"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.retain"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="home.moveItemUp($index)">^</button>
      </div>

 </div>
```

Despite what the docs say on the [angular-dragula site](https://github.com/bevacqua/angularjs-dragula), you need to put the `dragula-model` attribute on the *container* into which you put the repeating items.  Not the `ng-repeat` itself.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in ng-repeat track by $index.

Comment: Tried that.  Same thing.